Allow multiple users to access my VPS using SSH-client configuration from the same host
I would like to know how to allow multiple users to access my VPS using SSH.
I tried to edit ~/.ssh/config because i expected it to manage users access from the same remote IP.
As I see, when you register for a VPS Droplet, you generate a public key and assign it to an user. That's donne and I have already logged in with them to the root user. It generated a config file for that user on my local machine.
However, I added a second user ron on the Droplet and created an authorized_keys file for that user to allow me log in with that user on SSH. This requires me to create a config file on my machine in order to log in as both users (ron and root). Here is the file I created (The IP address given is just an example):
Host 161.00.100.100
        HostName 161.00.100.100
        User ron
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/private_key_for_ron
        IdentitiesOnly yes

Host 161.00.100.100
        HostName 161.00.100.100
        User root
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/private_key_for_root
        IdentitiesOnly yes

After creating this, I can only SSH in to the remote server as user ron and not root. In case it's helpful, the remote server on DO is Ubuntu and my local machine is Debian.
What am I doing wrong?

what exact command are you using to log in? do you give the complete user  ron@host or just by Host? if you comment out the root config does the ron config work?

The config file will use the first match from the config file. Since you use the same ip for both it will always match on the first entry. I would just give them different short-names (like ron and root) and use those.

You may just need to name the Host to be two different names
Host do-ron
        HostName 161.00.100.100
        User ron
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/private_key_for_ron
        IdentitiesOnly yes

Host do-root
        HostName 161.00.100.100
        User root
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/private_key_for_root
        IdentitiesOnly yes

ssh do-ron
ssh do-root


Thanks for your response. Strangely enough, DO for some reason overwrote the authorized_key file for the root user with old values. I didn't do anything to initiate that, I don't think. Anyway, your response was still instructive, and I named each Host as you instructed, and connected as you instructed. Cheers!
